# How do I pass multiple commands to PowerShell from a shortcut file?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

Simple wish for a Windows shortcut: I want to open a PowerShell window in a specific directory, and then have the shortcut enter and run a command.

This is how it looks right now when editing the "Target" of the shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd 'C:\eARKIV\Programmer\Android ADB'" -Command 'test'
```

The directory change works, but I get the below error when trying to enter an input through the shortcut:

```
"Set-Location : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Command'."
```

How can I circumvent this and get it to work?  :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only *one* `-Command` argument is supported; everything after (the first) `-Command` becomes part of the command to execute in the new session<sup>[1]</sup>, as `powershell -?` explains
.

To pass *multiple* commands, use `;` inside the `"..."` string passed to the (one and only)
`-Command` parameter:

```
... -NoExit -Command "cd 'C:\eARKIV\Programmer\Android ADB'; & 'test'"
```

Note that `-Command` must be the *last* argument passed.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Therefore, `-Command 'test'` accidentally became *additional arguments* passed to your `cd` (`Set-Location`) command inside the new PowerShell session, and that's what the error complained about - which also implies that the `cd` command did *not* succeed in changing the current location (working directory)</sup>

<sup>[2] Technically, you may follow `-Command` with *multiple* arguments, but they all become part of the code that PowerShell executes in the new session. For conceptual clarity and to avoid (more severe) escaping and quoting headaches, it is preferable to pass all of the commands as a *single*, `"..."`-quoted string.</sup>